# Using Terraform module source from a git bundle file

Tags: terraform

We're creating a Git bundle using `git_repo$ git bundle create repo.bundle HEAD`
Then take the file, push it to the server ( where we can clone, fetch from it )

But now we want to use this bundle in the remote server - as the Terraform's module `source=` parameter, is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terraform does not support using a bundle file as a repository. It requires a real Git repository accessible over the Git protocol, HTTP, HTTPS, or SSH.

Comment: I'm not questioning your answer but have you seen this `terraform-bundler`: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/33061